# Wrong week-ending date using 'to.weekly' function in 'xts' package

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a really odd issue... I am using the `to.weekly` and `to.period` function to convert a daily `xts` object to weekly data. In most instances, I get the week-ending date as a Friday (`day.of.week` function will return 5) (e.g. `"2010-01-08"`, `"2011-02-11"`), but there are a few cases where I get something other than Friday (Saturday/Sunday/Thursday/etc.)

I have tried `to.weekly` and `to.period(x, period = 'weeks')` and both return the same problem.

Why is this happening? Is there a work-around for this??

Thanks!!

**[EDIT: EXAMPLE BELOW]**

```
test.dates <- as.Date(c("2010-04-27","2010-04-28","2010-04-29","2010-04-30","2010-05-03","2010-05-04","2010-05-05","2010-05-06","2010-05-07","2010-05-10","2010-05-11","2010-05-12","2010-05-13","2010-05-14","2010-05-17","2010-05-18","2010-05-19","2010-05-20","2010-05-21","2010-05-22","2010-05-24","2010-05-25","2010-05-26","2010-05-27","2010-05-28","2010-06-01","2010-06-02","2010-06-03","2010-06-04"))

test.data <- rnorm(length(test.dates),mean=1,sd=2)

test.xts <- xts(x=test.data,order.by=test.dates)

#Function that takes in a vector of zoo/xts objects (e.g. "2010-01-08") and returns the day of the week for each
dayofweek <- function(x) {
 placeholder <- vector("list",length=length(x))
 names(placeholder) <- x

 for(i in 1:length(x)) {placeholder[[i]] <- month.day.year(x[i])}
 placeholder2 <- rep(NA,times=length(x))

 for(i in 1:length(x)) {placeholder2[i] <- day.of.week(placeholder[[i]][[1]],placeholder[[i]][[2]],placeholder[[i]][[3]])}
 return(placeholder2)}
```

This returns the date(s) that are not Friday: `time(to.weekly(test.xts))[dayofweek(time(to.weekly(test.xts))) != 5]`

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Dirk, example included above! Thanks!

Comment: @Ray Bao please include the packages you are using.  `day.of.week` and `month.day.year` are not functions in base R (nor is `xts,` but I know what package that comes from)

Comment: Zach, `day.of.week` and `month.day.year` are part of the `chron` package which is a part of `zoo` (and by extension, `xts`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your example:

1. Your `dayofweek` function is a bit cumbersome, and probably incorrect in its results.
2. Your example dates is missing some dates, such as 05-23-2010.

Here is a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
library(xts)
test.dates <- as.Date(c("2010-04-27","2010-04-28","2010-04-29","2010-04-30","2010-05-03","2010-05-04","2010-05-05","2010-05-06","2010-05-07","2010-05-10","2010-05-11","2010-05-12","2010-05-13","2010-05-14","2010-05-17","2010-05-18","2010-05-19","2010-05-20","2010-05-21","2010-05-22","2010-05-24","2010-05-25","2010-05-26","2010-05-27","2010-05-28","2010-06-01","2010-06-02","2010-06-03","2010-06-04"))
test.data <- rnorm(length(test.dates),mean=1,sd=2)
test.xts <- xts(x=test.data,order.by=test.dates)
test.weekly <- to.weekly(test.xts)

library(lubridate)
test.weekly[wday(test.weekly, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE) != "Fri"]
```

The only result of this function is

```
           test.xts.Open test.xts.High test.xts.Low test.xts.Close
2010-05-22     -1.705749      1.273982    -2.084203      -1.502611
```

The problem of course, is that this week ends on `05-23-2010`, but that date is not present in the time series.  Therefore, `to.weekly` uses the next closest date as the end point, which is `05-22-2010`. This is the source of your problem.

Here is a better example, which reveals no issue with the `to.weekly` function.

```
library(lubridate); library(xts)   
test.dates <- seq(as.Date("1900-01-01"),as.Date("2011-10-01"),by='days')
test.dates <- test.dates[wday(test.dates)!=1 & wday(test.dates)!=7] #Remove weekends
test.data <- rnorm(length(test.dates),mean=1,sd=2)
test.xts <- xts(x=test.data,order.by=test.dates)
test.weekly <- to.weekly(test.xts)
test.weekly[wday(test.weekly, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE) != "Fri"]
```

Comment: I assumed that `to.weekly` always returned the Friday, even under circumstances where there isn't a Friday-stamped date in the data vector--but now I realize that's not the case.

Comment: @Ray Bao:  That explains your issue.  I'm glad you've solved your problem.  If my answer was sufficient for you to find a solution, please click the check box to "accept" it.